# Converting entity class to record how can I do it in the right way

Tags: .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I want to convert this class to record

```
    public partial class PathCategory
    {
        public PathCategory()
        {
            DocumentPaths = new HashSet<DocumentPath>();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<DocumentPath> DocumentPaths { get; set; }
    }
```

so all I do is replace **partial class** with **record** to be like this

```
public record PathCategory
```

**Is that it, or are there any best practices I should follow?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public record PathCategory(Guid Id, string Category = null,ICollection<DocumentPath> DocumentPaths = null);

OR

public record PathCategory(Guid Id, string Category = null,ICollection<DocumentPath> DocumentPaths = documentPaths)
{
    readonly ICollection<DocumentPath> documentPaths = new();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).